# Django convert article.id into CSS class

Tags: css, django

I was wondering how I could call an article.id with a CSS class using Django +1.8

here is an example:

```
{% for a in article %}
    <div class="{% a.id %}"> #How to get a unique id for each article in a CSS class?
        <h2>{{ a.titre }}</h2>
        <a href='{% url "article.views.article_id" a.id %}'>Readmore</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I was thinking to something like this, but can't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `<div class="{{ a.id }}">` not `<div class="{% a.id %}">`.

Comment: What's the difference between {% ... %} and {{ ... }} ?

Comment: `{%  %}` would render template tags, like the `{% for ... %}` you have, whereas `{{  }}` is only used in rendering template variables.

Answer (score 1):

you should use [django variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/templates/#variables) instead of [django template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/templates/#tags)

```
{% for a in article %}
<div class="{{ a.id }}"> # < ------ 
    <h2>{{ a.titre }}</h2>
    <a href='{% url "article.views.article_id" a.id %}'>Readmore</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```